# How to make Regex match expression exact number of times, not exact number or less

Tags: python, regex

I have Python Regex that is supposed to extract from string only cases when there are four numbers in row:

```
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS? OF OPERATIONS?.+?Revenues?.+?Operating expenses?.+?Interest expenses?.+?per.+?Subordinated units.+?\s(\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?)
```

However, it also matches cases with three numbers in a row, but not two.
I tried to fix it by specifying min and max length as follows:

```
CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS? OF OPERATIONS?.+?Revenues?.+?Operating expenses?.+?Interest expenses?.+?per.+?Subordinated units.+?\s(\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s){4,4}
```

However, in this case I am getting error `catastrophic backtracking` when there is no match as opposed to proper result - `no match`.

How can I modify this part `(\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?\s\(?\d*[.]?(\d+)?\)?)` without changing the rest of Regex as it's needed to identify other specific patterns? In other words, I cannot touch this part: `CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS? OF OPERATIONS?.+?Revenues?.+?Operating expenses?.+?Interest expenses?.+?per.+?Subordinated units.+?\s`.

Example of text I am working with is below:

```
Table of Contents Part I. Financial Information Item 1. Financial Statements Noble Midstream Partners LP Consolidated Statements of Operations and Comprehensive Income (in thousands except per unit amounts unaudited) Three Months Ended March 31 2018 2017 Revenues Midstream Services - Affiliate 64263 50314 Midstream Services - Third Party 11360 0 Crude Oil Sales - Third Party 22110 0 Total Revenues 97733 50314 Costs and Expenses Cost of Crude Oil Sales 21439 0 Direct Operating 17148 11401 Depreciation and Amortization 11329 2449 General and Administrative 10442 2742 Total Operating Expenses 60358 16592 Operating Income 37375 33722 Other (Income) Expense Interest Expense Net of Amount Capitalized 1033 267 Investment Income (2868) (1065) Total Other Income (1835) (798) Income Before Income Taxes 39210 34520 Income Tax Provision 74 0 Net Income 39136 34520 Less: Net (Loss) Income Attributable to Noncontrolling Interests (225) 10178 Net Income Attributable to Noble Midstream Partners LP 39361 24342 Less: Net Income Attributable to Incentive Distribution Rights 819 0 Net Income Attributable to Limited Partners 38542 24342 Net Income Attributable to Limited Partners Per Limited Partner Unit - Basic and Diluted Common Units 0.97 0.77 Subordinated Units 0.97 0.77 Weighted Average Limited Partner Units Outstanding - Basic Common Units 23683 15903 Subordinated Units 15903 15903 Weighted Average Limited Partner Units Outstanding - Diluted Common Units 23698 15909 Subordinated Units 15903 15903 The accompanying notes are an integral part of these financial statements. 3 Table of Contents Noble Midstream Partners LP Consolidated Balance Sheets (in thousands unaudited) March 31 2018 December 31 2017 ASSETS Current Assets Cash and Cash Equivalents 24924 18026 Restricted Cash 0 37505 Accounts Receivable - Affiliate 27584 27539 Accounts Receivable - Third Party 15778 2641 Other Current Assets 4076 389 Total Current Assets 72362 86100 Property Plant and Equipment Total Property Plant and Equipment Gross 1161012 706039 Less: Accumulated Depreciation and Amortization (50142) (44271) Total Property Plant and Equipment Net 1110870 661768 Intangible Assets Net 334435 0 Goodwill 111145 0 Investments 79648 80461 Deferred Charges 3218 1429 Total Assets 1711678 829758 LIABILITIES Current Liabilities Accounts Payable - Affiliate 3968 1616 Accounts Payable - Trade 211399 109893 Other Current Liabilities 3110 2876 Total Current Liabilities 218477 114385 Long-Term Liabilities Long-Term Debt 435000 85000 Asset Retirement Obligations 11791 10416 Other Long-Term Liabilities 3758 3727 Total Liabilities 669026 213528 EQUITY Partners' Equity Limited Partner Common Units (23758 and 23712 units outstanding respectively) 655602 642616 Subordinated Units (15903 units outstanding) (159203) (168136) General Partner 819 520 Total Partners' Equity 497218 475000 Noncontrolling Interests 545434 141230 Total Equity 1042652 616230 Total Liabilities and Equity 1711678 829758 The accompanying notes are an integral part of these financial statements. 4 Table of Contents Noble Midstream Partners LP Consolidated Statements of Cash Flows (in thousands unaudited) Three Months Ended March 31 2018 2017 Cash Flows From Operating Activities Net Income 39136 34520 Adjustments to Reconcile Net Income to Net Cash Provided by Operating Activities Depreciation and Amortization 11329 2449 Dividends from Equity Method Investee Net of Income 393 0 Unit-Based Compensation 321 127 Other Adjustments for Noncash Items Included in Income 167 95 Changes in Operating Assets and Liabilities Net of Assets Acquired and Liabilities Assumed Increase in Accounts Receivable (2520) (3322) Decrease in Accounts Payable (836) (2518) Other Operating Assets and Liabilities Net (2387) 874 Net Cash Provided by Operating Activities 45603 32225 Cash Flows From Investing Activities Additions to Property Plant and Equipment (161509) (32298) Black Diamond Acquisition Net of Cash Acquired (650131) 0 Additions to Investments 0 (414) Distributions from Cost Method Investee 419 123 Net Cash Used in Investing Activities (811221) (32589) Cash Flows From Financing Activities Distributions to Noncontrolling Interests (3007) (11267) Contributions from Noncontrolling Interests 409865 7087 Borrowings Under Revolving Credit Facility 405000 0 Repayment of Revolving Credit Facility (55000) 0 Distributions to Unitholders (19860) (13782) Revolving Credit Facility Amendment Fees and Other (1987) (236) Net Cash Provided by (Used in) Financing Activities 735011 (18198) Decrease in Cash Cash Equivalents and Restricted Cash (30607) (18562) Cash Cash Equivalents and Restricted Cash at Beginning of Period 55531 57421 Cash Cash Equivalents and Restricted Cash at End of Period 24924 38859 The accompanying notes are an integral part of these financial statements. 5 Table of Contents Noble Midstream Partners LP Consolidated Statement of Changes in Equity (in thousands unaudited) Partnership Common Units Subordinated Units General Partner Noncontrolling Interests Total December 31 2017 642616 (168136) 520 141230 616230 Net Income 23058 15484 819 (225) 39136 Contributions from Noncontrolling Interests 0 0 0 409865 409865 Distributions to Noncontrolling Interests 0 0 0 (3007) (3007) Distributions to Unitholders (11575) (7765) (520) 0 (19860) Black Diamond Equity Ownership Promote Vesting (1) 1215 1214 (2429) 0 Unit-Based Compensation 321 0 0 0 321 Other (33) 0 0 0 (33) March 31 2018 655602 (159203) 819 545434 1042652 (1) See Note 2. Basis of Presentation
```

Comment: `exact number of times, not exact number or less` your heading of question is giving me hard time to understand what it actually means

Comment: Let me try to clarify it. Right now I am searching for sequence of four numbers in my Regex. However, it also accepts sequence with three numbers as well which is not what I need. I need it only to find sequences of four numbers and in other cases to give me ```no match```.

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/ReSBQK/1/)

Comment: Thank you - works! What's the role of this part ```?:```?

Comment: `?:` makes group non capturing

Comment: If you could explain how/why it works, I would really appreciate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196415/discussion-between-code-maniac-and-user3151858).